# intialize function of terra package produces fatal error

Tags: r, raster, fatal-error, terra

I am using the initialize function in the terra package to create a raster in RStudio. According to the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/terra/terra.pdf), this function should work with for large rasters, but I am getting a fatal error in RStudio when I try to create a 10,000 x 10,000 raster with a single value for all cells.

Using the example code works as expected

```
r <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=5, xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=5)
z <- init(r, fun=8) # works
```

However, when I increase the dimensions to 10k x 10k, the fatal error occurs.

```
r <- rast(ncols=10000, nrows=10000, xmin=0, xmax=10000, ymin=0, ymax=10000)
z <- init(r, fun=8) # crashes
```

Watching the Activity Monitor on my Macbook Pro shows that memory pressure spikes when running the code with the RStudio process exceeding 80GB of RAM. I have 16GB of RAM on my computer so I'm thinking the problem may be related to some memory issue?

I'm not sure if the function is not working as intended or if the issue is with RStudio. Or am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My specs:
OS: Monterey 12.0.1
Chip: Apple M1 Pro.
R version: 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
RStudio version: 2021.9.1.372 "Ghost Orchid"

Edit:

terra version: 1.4.22

I tried two solutions recommended by rhijmans in the link from @FKneip but both resulted in the same fatal error as before.

```
r <- rast(ncols=10000, nrows=10000) # works

values(r) <- 1 # crashes
z <- init(r, 1, filename="test.tif", datatype="INT1U") # crashes
```

Comment: Seems more likely to be an issue with R itself. Have you searched SO for advice about how to approach memory issues?

Comment: Agree with @IRTFM, definitely a mem issue. Have you seen [creating a large raster hangs R](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/165)?

Comment: I am working with lots of multi-gigabyte rasters right now and I have had a variety of issues with memory, but never fatal errors that cause it to abort. In other cases it just gives an error message and the process fails but there are no issues with R or RStudio. And the initialize function is specifically supposed to handle large rasters, unless I am misreading the documentation.

Comment: @FKneip Thanks for the link, it looks like there might be some workaround for my issue. It does seem to be an issue with initialize function, rather than with R.

Comment: I think you should make sure you have completely up-to-date installations of all its requirements/dependencies and then see if it also happens outside Rstudio. If it does then submit another bug report. `Suggests: parallel, tinytest, ncdf4, sf (>= 0.9-8), deldir, XML, raster
LinkingTo: Rcpp
Imports: methods, Rcpp
SystemRequirements: C++11, GDAL (>= 2.2.3), GEOS (>= 3.4.0), PROJ (>=
        4.9.3), sqlite3`

Comment: When I run the last section of code I instead get: `> r <- rast(ncols=10000, nrows=10000) # works
> 
> values(r) <- 1  ## not a crash, an error ##
Error in y@ptr$setValues(values, opt) : std::bad_alloc
> z <- init(r, 1, filename="test.tif", datatype="INT1U") ## not a crash ... an error ##
Error in x@ptr$initv(fun, opt) : std::bad_alloc`

Comment: Ok tomorrow I'll try updating those packages and see if that helps. Interesting that you are getting an error but not crashing. I notice that everytime I try a version of the code my RStudio process gets to ~80GB of memory at the time of failure. I have ~360GB available on disk so if it's using that it shouldn't be running out.

Comment: This is a bug that has been fixed in the development version of terra. You can install it with `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`

Comment: @RobertHijmans I'm now getting `RcppFunctions.cpp:174:12: error: ‘PROJ_VERSION_MAJOR’ was not declared in this scope
  buffer << PROJ_VERSION_MAJOR << "." << PROJ_VERSION_MINOR << "." << PROJ_VERSION_PATCH;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`. I'll go to the repo and see if there are any system dependencies that need updating for Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @RobertHijmans After reinstalling pkg:Rcpp, I got same error.  I sent you an email with the full console transcript and `sessionInfo()` output.

Comment: With most recent version on github I'm getting no errors for the installation or from the code above. Thanks, Robert, for the very prompt and effective response to the bug report.

Comment: @RoberHijmans I tried installing the development version of terra using the code provided but I get an error: `configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.` I also tried installing Homebrew and following the instructions on github to compile from source code but that failed as well. Everything seemingly worked until here: `Sys.setenv("R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS" = "true")
zsh: unknown file attribute: _`. `remotes::install_github("rspatial/terra")
zsh: number expected`. On github it says it should work on Catalina and Big Sur, but I am on Monterey.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a true solution to the problem but it is a temporary workaround that I just found. Use the classify function in terra to reclassify an empty raster (see below). This also worked to reclassify an existing 10k x 10k raster already populated with values. See `?classify` for details on how to enter a matrix for the `rcl=` argument depending on the values of your raster.

```
r <- rast(ncols=10000, nrows=10000)
r
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 10000, 10000, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.036, 0.018  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 

x <- classify(r, rcl = matrix(c(NA,1), 1, 2, byrow = TRUE), right=NA) # does not crash
x
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 10000, 10000, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.036, 0.018  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
source      : memory 
name        : lyr.1 
min value   :     1 
max value   :     1
```